# How to run ajax script if the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I want the ajax script to execute when the page is refreshed.

My problem is that it doesn't work - the ajax script is not running.

Script:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

    var data = {};
        data.emailCodeResult = $('#emailCodeResult').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Oppa/view/viewOther.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function (result) {


            $("#prof_talent").val(result.oth_hobbies);
            $("#prof_recognition").val(result.oth_recognition);
            $("#prof_organization").val(result.oth_organization);
            $("#prof_workExperience").val(result.oth_workExperience);
            $("#prof_trainingPrograms").val(result.oth_trainingPrograms);
            $(".show-page[data-page=Profile_Other_info]").trigger("click"); 
        }
     });
            return false;
});
```

Comment: What, specifically, doesn't work?

Comment: @jsve it doesnt execute the script...if i put the script on a click event it works.

Comment: What is `$('#emailCodeResult').val()` when window loads?

Comment: @hjpotter92 its an integer generated by an another ajax. I use setinterval onit to run always.

Comment: @user3869809 deleting all the content from a question after it's been answered is unacceptable and can get you banned for doing it repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds from your comment that `$('#emailCodeResult').val()` is still empty when your AJAX call fires. Since you're using `setinterval` to constantly repopulate it, why not put a do/while loop before your AJAX call to make sure `data.emailCodeResult` gets content?

```
//helper function (see http://www.sitepoint.com/delay-sleep-pause-wait/)
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}

do{
    sleep(2000);
}
while($('#emailCodeResult').val() == 'undefined');
//AJAX call here
```

Comment: @Whymarrh whoops, it's a helper function. Code included in the edit.